# Error when loading views programatically

Tags: 7, views

In my views i added a link to go to some page that has a php code in it's body.
The code loading the same views.
The code:

`<?php

$view = views_get_view('charge_numbers');

$view->set_exposed_input();

$display_id = 'default';

$view->set_display($display_id);

$view->render();

print_r($view->preview());

?>`

The views load correctly but this error message appear:
[image]

I did this step in another website and it's work perfectly.
Some advices please.

Comment: set_exposed_input() requires a parameter - (http://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!view.inc/function/view%3A%3Aset_exposed_input/7). 
The reason it works on the other website is probably because you are not displaying the errors, if you have the Database Logging module enabled you will see the error on the admin back-end.

Comment: i tried to write parameters in the url, the message still showing.